# Zend Cli is not working after install of memcached

Tags: php, zend-framework, memcached

Error messages are here.
Please tell me how to resolve this errors.

```
# /usr/bin/php /var/www/zfcli.php -m mypage -c index -a index

Strict Standards: Declaration of SmartyPlugin::dispatchLoopStartup() should be compatible with Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract::dispatchLoopStartup(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request) in /var/www/application/plugins/SmartyPlugin.php on line 22

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Session_Exception' with message 'Session must be started before any output has been sent to the browser; output started in /var/www/application/plugins/SmartyPlugin.php/22' in /var/www/library/Zend/Session.php:443
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/library/Zend/Session/Namespace.php(143): Zend_Session::start(true)
#1 /var/www/application/Bootstrap.php(95): Zend_Session_Namespace->__construct('Default')
#2 /var/www/library/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/BootstrapAbstract.php(669): Bootstrap->_initSession()
#3 /var/www/library/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/BootstrapAbstract.php(622): Zend_Application_Bootstrap_BootstrapAbstract->_executeResource('session')
#4 /var/www/library/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/BootstrapAbstract.php(586): Zend_Application_Bootstrap_BootstrapAbstract->_bootstrap(NULL)
#5 /var/www/library/Zend/Application.php(355): Zend_Application_Bootstrap_BootstrapAbstract->bootstrap(NULL)
#6 /var/www/zfcli.php(56): Zend_Application->bootstrap()
#7 {main}
  thrown in /var/www/library/Zend/Session.php on line 443
```